# How can I run 3 functions in python from a different script?

Tags: python

I have 3 functions in a python script that I would like to run at the same time but from another python script, for example:

```
def a():
       print("\nphrase1")
def b():
       print("\nphrase2")
def c():
       print("\nphrase3")
```

I would like to run those 3 functions from a different file. Could anyone support me on that?

Comment: import the function in all your python script and run it. where is the issue?

Comment: I want to avoid executing them like this
a () b () c (), is there any other more professional way?

Comment: a(),b(),c() is the only professional way it know in python. I think i am still not clear with the issue

Comment: do you mean run those functions by 3 threads? At the same time? I do not think it is a good idea if it is not need it.

Comment: by "at the same time" you mean parallel?

Comment: for example with threading I do not know how this could be done

Comment: yes that's what I mean

Comment: You should add clarifications to your question rather than in the comments.  Anyway, there is [Thread Based Parallelism](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading) for I/O bound tasks and [Process Based Parellelism](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) for CPU bound task.  Do you know which one you want?  There are Youtube video tutorials showing how to use both of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you copy the program with the functions to the same folder as the program you want to run them

```
from yourprogram import a, b, c
#code
a()
b()
c()
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose if all above function is inside module `fun.py` then use below code snippet to run all of it -

```
import fun
for i in dir(fun):
    item = getattr(fun,i) 
    if callable(item):
        item()
```

dir(fun) retrieves all the attributes of module fun. If the attribute is a callable object, call it. **Just a note, it will call everything which is callable in the fun module**.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: This is a really bad idea, you have no idea what callable attributes the module will have other than the intended functions. For example if it contains `from collections import Counter` then this will be a callable attribute of the module.